# Installing tcl/tk under Linux Centos 7 for use with Perl 5 - Missing a step?

Tags: linux, perl, installation, tcl, tk-toolkit

Running Perl 5 on Centos 7 and trying to install tcl/tk.

I've installed tk, tk-devel, tcl and tcl-devel using yum.  The yum install appears to work fine.  In fact, I re-ran the yum commands and saw a "nothing to be done" type of message.

In my perl file, the only code (after a declaration) is either

```
use tk;
```

Or

```
use Tk;
```

I'm not sure which is correct.  However, either one produces an error when I run the file -

```
Can't locate tk.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./test.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 4.
```

If I do a "find" from / searching for tk.pm the file is not found.

After the initial failure I found this on a site, which appears to be an additional step?

```
to install
tcl-8.5.13-4.el7.x86_64
tcl-devel-8.5.13-4.el7.x86_64
```

Invoking either one from the Linux command line generates a file not found error.

If I do a "find" from / searching for either file nothing is found.

It seems obvious I am missing something, but have no idea what it night be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perl module is [Tk.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk). RPMs for Perl modules generally follow the pattern:

```
Module      RPM
------      ---
Foo::Bar    perl-Foo-Bar
```

So run:

```
yum install perl-Tk
```

and in your script, do:

```
use Tk;
```

Comment: Yes - should anyone else have this situation, the above information corrected the issue.